# xpath to extract all different id in yahoo pipes

Tags: xpath, extract, feed, pipe, yahoo

I'm trying to build an rss feed from my website page by using yahoo pipes tool.

I be able to extract only one id from a web page by using "xphat fetch page" from yahoo pipes:

```
//*[@id="ctr3262_MainView_ViewBlog_lstBlogView_lnkEntry_0"
```

The others id are different: `..lstBlogView_lnkEntry_1`, `..lstBlogView_lnkEntry_2` and so on.

This is a portion of html file:

```
< div class="vbEntry" >
< h2 >
< a id="ctr3262_MainView_ViewBlog_lstBlogView_lnkEntry_1" rel="bookmark" href="http://www.site.com/blogs/EntryId/12">word1-word2-word3 < /a >
< /h2 > 
< div class="vbHeader dnnClear" >
from < a href='http:/www.site.com/ipse dixit' > ipse dixit < /a > , 
< span id="ctr3262_MainView_ViewBlog_lstBlogView_lblPublishDate_1" >sunday 7 december 2012 17:31 < /span >
< div class="dnnRight" >< /div >
< /div >
```

How can I view all ID from my page?

Comment: Please fix your input, the HTML is horribly messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for all elements with id where id contains a text use this

```
"//*[contains(@id, 'lstBlogView_lnkEntry_') ]"
```

all elements with id:

```
"//*[@id ]"
```

all ids:
Take the answer from @Jens Erat

Comment: Thank you. I have used your first code and it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can address attributes by using an attribute step, this XPath expression will query all `id` attributes in the document:

```
//@id
```